# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr]

Tags: spring

Technology used

1. Java 8
2. Maven 3.5.0

Getting this exception when i try to run my maven project using eclipse on tomcat 6.0 :-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

applicationcontext.xml includes

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
    http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
    http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">
```

pom.xml contains dependency for dwr

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
    <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2-RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```